# Error al configurar parámetros de BD en appsettings.json en .NET Core 6

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, nuget

Tengo una duda con respecto a cómo configurar mis parámetros en el `appsettings.json` de mi aplicación web en .NET Core 6.

Pasa que en mi SQLServer ingreso de la siguiente manera:
[image: DB]

Pasa que mi problema surge cuando trato de crear una migración con el Nuget Manager Console y me arroja el siguiente error:
[image: Error]

Como bien dice ahí, supongo yo es por el `appsettings.json`, mismo que lo tengo configurado de la siguiente manera (y no se cómo configurarlo correctamente e intentado de mil formas):

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(LocalDb)\Demo;Database=DBCualquiera; User Id=LAPTOP-CODIGO\NameMio;Password:"
  },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme...

Comment: ¿Has instalado los paquetes de Entity Framework Core necesarios para ello?

Comment: Si, el tools, sqlserver y Entity framework tal cual. Creo que el error vienen porque en mi program.cs no tiene las configuraciones correctas, averigüe que el startup.cs se usaba antes y con el .net core 6 solo se trabaja con el program.cs. aún no sé cómo configurarlo bien.

Comment: Al momento de este comentario, no veo que exista un program.cs en tu pregunta, sería bueno que lo incluyeras. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Debes compilar tu proyecto antes de adicionar una Nueva Migración.

En caso de no funcionar aún, intenta cambiar tu cadena de conexión a ésta otra:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=NombreServidor; Initial Catalog=NombreBBDD; User ID=NombreUsuario; Password=Contraseña; Integrated Security=False"
  },
......
}
```